# Why does it take time to site to go up after I change the domain it was hosted?

Tags: google-app-engine, hosting

I hosted my website using appengine ,after I change the subdomain on which it was hosted to another subdomain,It took some hours to again go live.Why is it so,and what takes the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://support.powerdnn.com/KB/a604/dns-propagation-and-why-it-takes-so-long-explained.aspx

> **Why Does DNS Take So Long to Propagate?** You have registered your
>   domain name, uploaded your website to one of our web servers, and
>   asked your registrar to either use our name servers or to point your
>   "A" record to your web server's IP address. Once that this is done,
>   what's the hold up?
>
> When your website's address is entered into a browser, the computer
>   requests the IP address of the server housing your site from your
>   Internet Server Providers (ISP) DNS records. If the site is not listed
>   in the records it queries registrars to find out who the DNS start of
>   authority (SOA) is for your website. If you're using your registrar's
>   name server as your SOA, it looks up the "A" record for your domain
>   and returns the IP address of the server listed. If you are using our
>   name servers, the registrar points the browser to our DNS servers to
>   determine the IP Address for your domain name. From there the request
>   is sent to the server the domain is hosted on which then provides the
>   browser with the website.
>
> To speed the loading of websites, each ISP caches a copy of DNS
>   records for a period of time, sometimes up to 48 hours. This means
>   that they make their own copy of the registrars' master DNS records,
>   and reads from them locally instead of making a direct request to the
>   domain registrar every time a request for your site is made. This
>   speeds up web surfing quite a bit by: decreasing the return time it
>   takes for a web browser to request a domain lookup and get an answer
>   and reducing the amount of traffic on the web.  The downside to
>   caching the master DNS records is because each company or ISP only
>   updates their records every few days, any changes you make to your DNS
>   records are not reflected between those updates. Although our DNS
>   servers update every 15 minutes, the time between updates system wide
>   is not standardized so the delay can range from a few hours to several
>   days. This slow updating of the cached records is called propagation
>   delay because your website's DNS information is being propagated
>   across all DNS servers on the web. Once completed, everyone can visit
>   your new website.